# How to use the argument of Pattern.compile?

Tags: java, string

Here is an example I'm using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*<img[^>]*src=\"([^\"]*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("<img src=\"aoeuaoeu\"/>");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

So the output of this code is: `aoeuaoeu`.

What do I need to put in the parentheses to search something in a text, like in the example?

Comment: Note that in the given use case example regex is the wrong tool for the job. HTML is not a regular language. Just use a HTML parser such as [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of the pattern is a [*regular expression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It must conform to a regular expression language, a widely used way to describe such patterns.

Although the fine details of regular expressions are very important to understand, and are often subjects of lengthy college courses, you can learn the basics by following a simple tutorial [[link]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), following numerous examples, and trying your hand at writing regular expressions for your particular purposes.

There are many implementations of regular expression engines, with widely different capabilities. To learn the particulars of the Java "dialect" of regular expressions, follow [the documentation of the `Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: You wrote: The first parameter of the pattern ... must conform to **a** regular expression language. Should it not be **the** regular expression language (syntax), the one acceptable to Java?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Java's regular expression language is one of many dialects of regular expression language, so yes, your statement is more specific. You are welcome to edit answers for clarity etc., your reputation level lets you do that.

Comment: Ok, so the first parameter is a regular expression! Thanks, I know about regex. So with the documentation I'll try to implement this in my code. Thank to all for your help.